# interact objects in dropdownlist when create in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, code-first

I have 2 classes: User and Role, an user has a role

```
public class User : IPrincipal
{        
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Created date")]
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }        

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Password question")]
    public string PasswordQuestion { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Password anwser")]
    public string PasswordAnswer { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Active")]
    public bool IsApproved { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last login date")]
    public DateTime LastLoginDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last password changed date")]
    public DateTime LastPasswordChangedDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last activity date")]
    public DateTime LastActivityDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }

    public virtual IIdentity Identity { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsInRole(string role)
    {
        if (Role.Name.ToLower() == role.ToLower())
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
} 

public class Role
{
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Role name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I created UserController with read/write entity, in Create method, I created ViewBag.Role contains list of role

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.Role = new SelectList(db.Roles, "RoleId", "Name");
    return View();
}
```

In create view:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Role)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownList("Role")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Role.RoleId) @* I don't know this is correct? *@
</div>
```

In create view with HttpPost attribute, when user choose one role, and submit, I can't get a value of role.
Anyone who know the way to add role into user by select dropdownlist? I means, when I drop down list role and select item in there, and submit, I add one user row into table
Thank you

Comment: Please post your action method from your controller.

Comment: Why use a ViewBag here? Why not create a view model with one IEnum of roles and a int SelectedRoleId and bind against those, will look nicer in code....

Answer (score 0):

You can expose the RoleId foreign key by adding it as a property of User.

Then your view would look like

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RoleId, (SelectList)ViewBag.Role)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RoleId)
</div>
```